# Why do my programatically added TableRows not float in line with my table-header?

Tags: java, android, textview, tablelayout, tablerow

**MY GOAL:**

I am trying to populate a table(with a headline that I created in my xml) with a bunch of programmatically added views. The plan is to add some `TextViews` to a `TableRow` and then add that `TableRow` to the final table that created. I tried to follow [this tutorial](http://en.androidwiki.com/wiki/Dynamically_adding_rows_to_TableLayout).

**MY PROBLEM:**

The programmatically added views do not go inline with the columns that the xml-created TextViews dictate. Please see the following screenshot:

[image]

MY CODE:
1.) XML

```
<TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableViewTable"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_EvalProblemTableRight"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_EvalProblemTableBottom"
                    android:text="@string/str_EvalProblemNumber"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_EvalProblemTableRight"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_EvalProblemTableBottom"
                    android:text="@string/str_EvalProblemString"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_EvalProblemTableRight"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_EvalProblemTableBottom"
                    android:text="@string/str_EvalProblemCorrectSolution"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_EvalProblemTableRight"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_EvalProblemTableBottom"
                    android:text="@string/str_EvalProblemUserSolution"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_EvalProblemTableRight"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_EvalProblemTableBottom"
                    android:text="@string/str_EvalProblemDuration"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </TableRow>            
        </TableLayout>
```

2.) JAVA:

```
public class EvalActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_eval);

        TableLayout tableViewTable = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableViewTable);

        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        Button b = new Button(this);
        b.setText("Button");
        b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        TextView t1 = new TextView(this);       
        t1.setText("I am textView1");
        t1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        TextView t2 = new TextView(this);       
        t2.setText("I am textView2");
        t2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        TextView t3 = new TextView(this);       
        t3.setText("I am textView3");
        t3.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        TextView t4 = new TextView(this);       
        t4.setText("I am textView3");
        t4.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        tr.addView(b);
        tr.addView(t1);
        tr.addView(t2);
        tr.addView(t3);
        tr.addView(t4);

        tableViewTable.addView(tr,(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)));
    }
```

How can I join the "hardcoded" xml-TableRow with the programatically added Views and Rows?

Comment: When dynamically adding widgets always assign the proper `LayoutParams` to the added views, this is important for `TableLayout` and `TableRows`. In your case the `TableRow` should have `TableLayout.LayoutParams` as `LayoutParams` and the views added to the `TableRow` should have `TableRow.LayoutParams`.

Answer (score 0):

Try manually adding an align rule to the layout parameters like this:

```
LayoutParams myParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
myParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT, R.id.tableColumnX);

TextView t3 = new TextView(this);       
t3.setText("I am textView3");
t3.setLayoutParams(myParams);
```

Comment: That sounds pretty straight forward. I'd love to try that. However, how or where do I define the Resource referenced with `R.id.tableColumnX`?

Comment: I just named it something random. Fill in your self-named table values.

Comment: Sure, sure. I totally got that. I'm just wondering how I Would reference a certain column!? Or do you suggest to reference a view from the first row?